# Can there be a context-sensitive pumping lemma?

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma, context-sensitive

A "pumping" property (words of a certain length imply the existence of loops in the language-defining mechanism) are known to exist for regular and context-free languages and a few more (usually used to disprove a language's membership to a certain class).

Within the discussion [around this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319662/pumping-lemma-for-context-sensitive-language), Daisy's answer suggests that there **can't be** a pumping lemma for context-sensitive languages - since they're so complex.

Is that true - can it be shown that there can't be some type of pumping property - and is there a good reference for that (or against that)?

Comment: Can you give a formal definition of "pumping lemma"? If not, there can be no such proof by principle.

Comment: Perhaps one can refute Parikh's theorem for context-sensitive languages, and this leads us to expect that no pumping lemma resembling the ones we know exists.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What do you mean? Clearly the prime numbers are context sensitive, and are not semilinear. So Parikh does not hold for context sensitive. That means that "linear pumping" does not apply. Like Raphael I am curious what other methods would be considered pumping.

Comment: @HendrikJan Right, so this rules out a lot of potential pumping lemmas. Perhaps that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: You're right, it comes down to knowing what exactly "pumping" is... I was hoping for some suggestions... What is *Parikh's theorem for context-sensitive languages*? I only found one for context-free languages.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: ...and how does it rule out a lot of potential pumping lemmas...?

Comment: @lukas.coenig There is no Parikh's theorem for context-sensitive languages, but there might have been one if there were a simple pumping lemma for context-sensitive languages.

Comment: @lukas.coenig See this paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X77901030.

Comment: AH! That's nice thinking!!

Comment: have wondered something like this myself. it would help to do a survey. there is a resemblance between the RL pumping lemma and a CFL version cited by YF. but what is the resemblance, and what would a generalization look like? this is essentially a research question, open afaik. try [cstheory.se], maybe migrate this question? also suggest further [chat]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some evidence that there is no pumping lemma for the context-sensitive
languages.

Of course, an answer hinges on the question what constitutes a pumping
lemma.  The weakest reasonable definition I could think of is this: A language
class $\mathcal{C}$ has a *pumping lemma* if there is a decidable ternary
predicate $P(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ where $P(g,w,d)$ means:

- $g$ is a word encoding a language $L(g)$ from $\mathcal{C}$ (think: grammar),
- $w$ is a word in the language encoded by $g$
- $d$ is a word encoding a *pumpable* computation/derivation for $w$ (think: NFA
  computation with repeated state or CFG derivation tree with repeated
  nonterminal). Here, *pumpable* means: there exist infinitely many words in $L(g)$.

Moreover, we want that given a language $L$ in $\mathcal{C}$ encoded by $g$,
for every sufficiently long word $w\in L$, there exists a word $d$ such that
$P(g,w,d)$.

For example, the pumping lemma for regular languages would give rise to
the predicate "$g$ encodes an $\varepsilon$-free NFA and $d$ encodes a
run that repeats a state and reads $w$". For suitable encodings, this
clearly satisfies the above conditions.

Now let us show that such a predicate does not exist for the context-sensitive
languages.

Observe that if a language class has a pumping lemma, then the infinity problem
(Given a grammar, does it generate an infinite language?) is recursively
enumerable: Given an encoding $g$, we can enumerate words $w$ and $d$ and check
whether $P(g,w,d)$. If we found such $w,d$, we answer 'yes', otherwise, we
continue the enumeration.

However, we show that the infinity problem for the context-sensitive languages
is not recursively enumerable. Recall that $\Pi_2^0$ is a level of the
arithmetic hierarchy that strictly includes the recursively enumerable
languages. Hence, it suffices to prove:

**Claim**: The infinity problem for the context-sensitive languages is $\Pi_2^0$-complete.

It is well-known that the infinity problem for recursively enumerable languages
is $\Pi_2^0$-complete (more often, one finds the formulation that the
finiteness problem is $\Sigma_2^0$-complete). Hence, it suffices to reduce the
latter problem to the infinity problem for the context-sensitive languages.

Given a TM $M$, we construct an LBA $A$ for the language
$$ \{u\#v \mid \text{$v$ is a shortlex-minimal accepting computation of $M$ on input $u$}\}. $$
Then, $L(A)$ is infinite iff $L(M)$ is infinite, which completes our proof.

Update: Tried to be clearer.
Update: Added example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42805/discussion-between-raphael-and-georg-zetzsche).